# PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest uncorrect results with the parameter page for Boursorama

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get data from the boursorama website, but when I send the request with the parameter "page", the result is the same if page = 1 or page = 50.

The URL is the following : http://www.boursorama.com/bourse/derives/turbos/

My goal is to get a list of products which are in the webpart called "Rechercher des Turbos, Call ou Put".

Following is the request :

```
$Data = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -URI "http://www.boursorama.com/ajax/ui/refresh.phtml/boursorama/block/bourse/derives/search/turbos?page=30" -Headers @{"X-Brs-Xhr-Request"="true";"X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"} -body "parameters[page]=30&class=Boursorama_Block_Bourse_Derives_Search_Turbos"
```

`$Data.content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but you can try :

```
$r=iwr http://www.boursorama.com/bourse/derives/turbos/?page=30
$r.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('td') |?{$_.classname -eq 'tdv-isin'} |select innerHTML
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert the object innerhtml to a string ?

Comment: try `select -expand innerHTML`

Comment: The filter page worked, but other filters like ssjacent=ACCOR doesn't work